# Pure JavaScript - how to add class to a class? Or change style in class

Tags: javascript, css

I have several classes named `.tag` on a click/mousedown action I want to either change `clear:both` to `clear:none` on all `.tag` items. Or add the class `.clearNone { clear:none; }` to all the tags.

What I've tried so far without luck:

```
function mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sizePanel, true);

    // Using ID works
    var tagsCol = document.getElementById("tags-col");
    tagsCol.classList.add("width100");

    // Using class does not
    var tag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
    tag.classList.add("clearNone");
};
```

CSS

```
.tag {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: both;
    @include rounded(4px);
}

.clearNone  { clear: none; }
```

How would you accomplish this? Note there are hundreds of `.tag`'s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that.

Instead, add a marker classname to a common ancestor element, then use a CSS rule:

```
.SomeClassName .tag {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What's the JavaScript part? I tried to do that in my code above

Comment: @LeonGaban: Just add that classname to any common ancestor element.

Comment: I don't understand, again this is what I just added now: `.clearNone .tag { clear: none; }` now again the javascript I tried is this `tag.classList.add("clearNone");` which does not work. :(

Comment: Do you understand what that selector means? You need to add that class to an element that contains all of the `.tag`s.

Answer (score 3):

To fix your issue directly, you need to loop over the returned elements:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
for (var x = 0; x < tags.length; x++)
    tags[x].classList.add("clearNone");
```

But as with [Slaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632056/791010), there is a better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: thx, getting this error btw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefinedapp.min.js:18 d` on the classList.add part, not sure why as I didn't get that on the `id` code.

Comment: @Leon Not sure why - [it should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesThorpe/nxe00kmu/)

Comment: @JamesThorpe the `.classList` property isn't supported on older browsers.

Comment: @Pointy The OP said it worked for him with `getElementById`, so I was working with that.  The issue isn't so much about `classList`, but rather the fact it was being applied to a collection rather than individual elements.

Comment: Ah yes I got this working now thanks! I have no idea how to implement @SLaks answer :( it's just the CSS part and I already have that, it's the JavaScript part I was missing... also I needed to add !important `.clearNone  { clear: none !important; }`

Comment: @LeonGaban just `document.body.classList.add("someClassName")` - it'll be much faster if you have lots of `.tag` elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code (edit thanks @Bergi)

```
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
for(var i=0; i<tags.length; ++i){ 
  if(typeof tags[i] === "object" && "classList" in tags[i]){
    tags[i].classList.add("clearNone");
  }
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `for in` enumerations on array-like objects!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: thanks @Bergi [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) ..... i did not know, is considered a bad practice